What problems did the USA's transatlantic communication face during World War II?
I would be interested to know which means of communication (transatlantic cable?) were affected by the war compared to the pre-war period.
Were new means of communication  discovered/developed?
I scrolled through, relatively speaking, the first page of Google search results and did not see anything that was essentially related to my question. A clue wouldn't hurt me.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

@MCW - I scrolled through, relatively speaking, the first page of Google search results and did not see anything that was essentially related to my question. A clue wouldn't hurt me.

@kipu39,Questions without preliminary research tend not to get answered.   WeAreTheMighty looks like the basis for further research.

National WWII museum and DISA both seem relevant.

https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71527/where-was-the-att-radio-station-in-1942-in-new-york/71528#71528 covers one link

@JonCuster - the link Bell System Technical Journal in your comment can't be reached.

@klpu39 - roger that, BSTJ now hosted at IEEE - https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6769471
